# Crash in WebView while swping

Tags: ios, crash, webkit

I have previous,current and next (three) web views in View controller. App Rarely crashes while swiping. 
(Note:these web views used to load content based on the current index i.e. swiping index)

[image]

Comment: its giving bad access. u should check if index is (null). and didnt got wht are u asking for. Show some code.

Comment: definitely index is not null. Like Photo viewer this is content Viewer nothing complex. This Page will be loaded with 3 web views based on the direction of  swipe (right || left ) contents of the each web view will be loaded.